# How to construct Date object instance and invoke its function on the same line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to construct a `Date` object and invoke the `getTimeZoneOffset()` function in the same line. However, chrome is giving me an error.

```
>  new Date().getTimeZoneOffset();

x  Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getTimeZoneOffset is not a function(…)
```

I created a random test object, and was able to instantiate the test object and call its function in the same line.

Why am I unable to do this with the Date object?

Comment: This is simple typo: `getTimezoneOffset` does not have a capital `Z`. It is correctly telling you that `getTimeZoneOffset` is not a function.

Comment: ah, thank you. i will delete my question shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is `getTimezoneOffset`, not `getTimeZoneOffset`. So, it just works:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

Of course, not needed in this case, but in cases when you want something to run first then use its return to call another function, you could use an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), like this:

```
(function () { return new Date() })().getTimezoneOffset()
```

And with ES6 arrow functions:

```
(() => new Date())().getTimezoneOffset()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

> Return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time

Result will be:
 **420**

You can read about this function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

Comment: np. you can leave it